# Xpage error message - Engine Exception name can't be null IBM WebSphere Application Server

Tags: xpages

I have created a simple xpage in Domino Designer/Server 9. When opening it, it give following error message:

Engine Exception

name can't be null

IBM WebSphere Application Server

I am not able to locate the source of this error. And strange thing is why IBM Websphere message is coming here!!

```
<xp:this.beforePageLoad>
<![CDATA[#{javascript:var catDb:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase("<server name>","catalog.nsf");
requestScope.DocCol = catDb.search("Form='Notefile'"); }]]>
</xp:this.beforePageLoad>
<xp:dataTable id="dataTable1" rows="30" value="#{javascript:return requestScope.DocCol;}" var="repCol" indexVar="repIndex">
    <xp:column id="column1">
        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{repCol.Pathname}">
        </xp:text>
    </xp:column>
</xp:dataTable>
```

Comment: Got it. It had a data table which was bound to a view column. Column name was "$6". Seems like we can't use these names. What if we want to connect to legacy applications. Do we need to modify the view column programmatic names always?

Comment: I have not seen any problems with $XXX column names so far. Can you paste your datatable code here? e.g. you can use "XYZ['$6'] instead of "XYZ.$6" in value bindings.

Comment: Now I receive same error when I am trying to provide document collection as data source for my data table. Here is code - <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:var catDb:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase("<server name>","catalog.nsf");
 requestScope.DocCol = catDb.search("Form='Notefile'");
}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
<xp:dataTable id="dataTable1" rows="30" value="#{javascript:return requestScope.DocCol;}" var="repCol" indexVar="repIndex">
<xp:column id="column1"><xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{repCol.Pathname}"></xp:text></xp:column>
</xp:dataTable>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to rework your code a little bit. Along this lines:

```
<xp:dataTable id="dataTable1" rows="30"
    value="#{javascript:return requestTools.getDocumentsByForm('Notefile');}"
    var="repCol" indexVar="repIndex">
    <xp:column id="column1">
        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{repCol.Pathname}">
        </xp:text>
    </xp:column>
</xp:dataTable>
```

Create a script library where you then implement the function. Something like:

```
var requestTools = {
      "isDebug" : function() { return false; },
      "debugDocumentsByForm" : function(formName) { return {"PathName" : "DemoPath"},
      "getDocumentsByForm" : function(formName) {
           if (requestTools.isDebug()) {
               return requestTools.debugDocumentsByForm(formName);
           } else if (!requestScope.DocCol) {
             // optimize this, add only the fields needed to JSON objects, so
             // recycling can happen
             var catDb:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase("<server name>","catalog.nsf");
             requestScope.DocCol = catDb.search("Form='"+formName+"'");
           }

            return requestScope.DocCol;
       }
}
```

This will allow you to tune the function without touching all XPages that use it. db.search is the slowest way to perform a search, so you only might use it for testing.

There is no code in the beforePageLoad event. You want to keep the data acquisition confined to your dataTable. Also consider to use a JSON object instead  of a document collection and a view or at least an FTSearch. db.Search is way to slow.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen. This works the way I wanted it to. Now I'll fetch my results in form of JSON instead of storing document collection in a scoped variable. Thanks much!!